# Inflate and attach common PreferenceCategory

Tags: android, preferenceactivity

I have a common PreferenceCategory named common.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceCategory
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <PreferenceScreen
        android:title="Common preference screen" />

</PreferenceCategory>
```

I would like inflate it and attach to different PreferenceScreen(s) (not all) in my PreferenceActivity hierarchy. I searched how to, but after many tries, I have not any solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently came up with a solution. It's maybe more complex than what you are looking for but here are the basics:

- There are two projects: a library and game that uses the library
- The idea is many games can use the same library (where I keep the common Java/XML code)
- On a single screen I can display both preferences from the common library code and game-specific code

I wrote a detailed blog [article](http://pilcrowpipe.blogspot.jp/2012/12/modular-approach-to-implementing.html), along with sample code and 2 Eclipse projects.

Comment: One thing to note though, is it doesn't supported nest preference categories within a single XML resource file. They'll need to be added as separate preference screens in separate files.